# How do I package xlwing and python code into a single xll?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, xll

I am trying to build an excel plugin at the moment to distribute. Because a large portion of the code base is in python, I am considering using xlwings.

Considering that most of the target audience will not have python installed, I would like to package xlwings and the python code into a single, standalone .xll file to distribute, similar to what py2exe does for executables.

How do I go about packaging the code with xlwings?

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* is not a programming question.

Comment: All right, I removed that phrase.